# Is there any way that I can share a website link with # on whatsApp

Tags: javascript, php, share, whatsapp

I am working on a project on https://discoverquran.com/, I would like to share a link on whatsApp e.g https://discoverquran.com/common-questions-about-islam#what-is-the-significant-of-fasting.
but on whatsApp the text after # is not displayed. Is there any solution to it.
I am using the following to share on whatsApp
`https://wa.me/?text=https://discoverquran.com/common-questions-about-islam#what-is-the-significant-of-fasting`

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution, whenever you want to pass a `string` as a GET Request which inculde space, or any special character then you have to encode it, you can use [UrlEncoder](https://www.urlencoder.org/) or a php function `urlencode()` or javascript function `encodeURI()`.

So your URL become `https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?text=https%3A%2F%2Fdiscoverquran.com%2Fcommon-questions-about-islam%23what-is-the-significant-of-fasting`

[image: https://api.whatsapp.com/send/?text=https%3A%2F%2Fdiscoverquran.com%2Fcommon-questions-about-islam%23what-is-the-significant-of-fasting]

Comment: Is there anyway this can be done on linkedIn as well.

Comment: It works for all, if you encode the link.